# Pointers getting mixed up in android

Tags: java, android, pointers, ant

I'm using ant to compile my android projects into debug apks. But sometimes when running my app, objects are getting mixed up and showing up at the wrong places.

For example:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/deviceText"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        style="@style/shadow"
        android:layout_column="0" />
<Button android:id="@+id/editDeviceButton"
        android:text="@string/edit"
        android:enabled="false" 
        android:layout_column="2" />
```

This is some code from profile.xml which is used in Profile.java. Here the @string/edit is a reference to the string "Edit", but instead of showing "Edit" in the app, is says "sdk" which is the text that should be assigned to the TextView. The "sdk" string is generated from Profile.java

To solve this problem I have to save the Profile.java file(which already exists) that use this xml file. And by save i mean just save it, not editing it at all, it is just as it were before.

Ant version:
Apache Ant version 1.8.0 compiled on April 9 2010

Comment: *To solve this problem I have to save the Profile.java file* - Do you expect it to work if you haven't saved your files?

Comment: Edited my post. The file already exists, I just have to save it, not editing it or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend instead of running just `ant install`, run `ant clean install`. This usually clears up any resource mixups like the one you are describing.

Comment: Just before this answer i discovered that deleting the class files in bin/ solved the problem, so this will work. Thanks!

Comment: This is a new thing since the modification to R in the latest tools, and is extremely annoying for eclipse builds, because I have to clean the build manually every time. Has anyone found an alternative solution in eclipse?